# Password Recovery webpart in CKS FBA is ignoring the configured email template

Tags: web-part, forms-authentication

I'm using the FBA solution from http://cks.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/94877#85179.

The issue I'm facing is that though FBA and the webparts seems to be working correctly, the password recovery webpart is something I couldn't find answer for.
If a user resets his/her password an email is sent to the user. Instead of containing the defined xslt content, the email contains the following text:

> Please return to the site and log in using the following information.
>   User Name: 
>   Password: somepassworkd

The XSLT files that are used for generating the emails from 'FBA Site Configuration' can be found under Site Settings. (/_layouts/FBA/emails/MembershipApproved.xslt)

for Password Recovery its already set to /_layouts/FBA/emails/PasswordRecovery.xslt which has a different text that I'm getting in the email.!!!

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because of how the web part sends out the custom email.  It relies on the membership control that it is based on to error out when sending the standard email - which it will on a standard SharePoint installation, as a standard installation doesn't have a 'mailsettings' section in the web.config that the control relies on.

So to get the email you're getting, you must have a 'mailsettings' section in your web.config.  Remove it, and you should start getting the templated email (as long as your SharePoint outgoing email settings are properly configured).

If you start using SharePoint 2010, you can use the SharePoint 2010 FBA Pack, which is based on the CKS solution, but this bug has been fixed. http://sharepoint2010fba.codeplex.com/